# Nexus 3 API lacks for maven group update

Tags: rest, api, nexus3

I am using [Nexus 3 Beta REST API](http://localhost/swagger-ui), but I discovered that it lacks for the `/beta/repositories/maven/group/{repo-group-name}` !!!

Nor the [Groovy API](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-scripting-examples) offers such kind of method.

Does anybody know as solution for that issue?

Comment: I need it too, and I didn't find any solution yet!

Comment: Nexus API has been updated https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-23080 .